# javascript - maintain loaded gltf in browser cache even after unmount / force context loss

Tags: reactjs, caching, three.js, 3d, browser-cache

I'm loading about 10MB worth of GLTF models into a three.js scene within React. As a user goes through the website experience, they hit the 3D model "scene", and my GLTF models are loaded. When they finish this scene, I do a little threejs cleanup, before I unmount the react component. However, if a user re-visits this scene - it goes through that whole loading process again.

**Is there a way to preserve the loaded objects in the browser cache somehow so that even after the react component is unmounted, the loaded model data is accessible to subsequent visits** / component mounts (even if it's only within the same browser session, before refresh, etc)?

Here's the model loading code:

```
loadGLB = loader => {
    if (sceneConfig.modelFormat === 'glb') {
      const dracoLoader = new DRACOLoader();
      dracoLoader.setDecoderPath('three/examples/js/libs/draco/');
      loader.setDRACOLoader(dracoLoader);
    }
  };

const loader = new GLTFLoader().setPath(models.modelPath);
this.loadGLB(loader);
loader.load(`${models.modelToLoad}.${sceneConfig.modelFormat}`, glb => {
      this.object = glb.scene;
      ...
});
```

and the cleanup:

```
componentWillUnmount() {
cancelAnimationFrame(this.frameId);
window.removeEventListener('resize', this.handleWindowResize);
this.container.removeChild(this.renderer.domElement);
this.renderer.forceContextLoss();
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Re-initiating a new WebGL context several times on the same page has some performance drawbacks. Most importantly, each new context has to re-upload all textures and geometries to the GPU, which is a bottleneck that leads to frame staggering and flickering. Not to mention all the memory and GC overhead you'll accumulate by cleaning + rebuilding the renderer, shaders, geometry, textures, etc. This is anecdotal, but FireFox usually gets bogged down for me by the time it's created its 3rd or 4th WebGL context, and I've had mobile devices just reload the page altogether when memory consumption gets too high.

Have you tried using [Portals](https://reactjs.org/docs/portals.html) so the `<canvas>` is outside of the React hierarchy? This way you can place the canvas wherever you'd like (in the background, for instance) and you can turn its visibility on/off without having to initiate a new WebGL context each time you want to show/hide it. You can simply stop the rendering and set `display: none` in CSS to hide the canvas, while still keeping everything in standby for when you need it again.

Something like this:

```
if (enabled) {
    renderer.render(scene, cam);
    renderer.domElement.style.display = "block";
} else {
    // Not rendering when canvas is hidden
    renderer.domElement.style.display = "none";
}
```

This is the approach we used on https://madeinhaus.com/ We have a single canvas in the background, and we only initiate it once. Then we show/hide it as needed without mounting and unmounting a new component each time.